# Getting field name from MySQL within a query where a value is not zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a number of categories and then a value against those values - I need to try and extract from that table (using MySQL only) the names of the categories where the value is not zero and the value itself.

For example:

```
ID   car   phone   gym   pension
1    200   15      12    20
2    0     15      12    25
3    0     0       0     30
4    0     0       0     0
5    150   20      12    0
```

In the above I need to get something like:

```
1 Car     200
1 Phone   15
1 Gym     12
1 Pension 20
2 Phone   15
2 Gym     12
2 Pension 25
3 Pension 30
5 Car     150
5 Phone   20
5 Gym     12
```

The below query returns me the correct ID and values but it also returns the zero values (except for ID 4) and not the category names:

```
SELECT id, car, phone, gym, pension from benefits where (car!=0 OR phone!=0 OR gym!=0 OR pension!=0)
```

I could do this in PHP but is it possible to do this just in MySQL?

Comment: Is there a reason for `(car!=0 OR phone!=0 OR gym!=0 OR pension!=0)` instead of `(car!=0 AND phone!=0 AND gym!=0 AND pension!=0)`

Comment: Because that isn't what he wants...

Comment: imo, Sadly, the output you require is how it should be held in the database originally. ;-/

Comment: @RyanVincent Happily, I agree with you

Comment: @RyanVincent unhappily I too agree with you but it is not :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT id, car AS col
FROM benefits
WHERE car!=0

UNION ALL

SELECT id, phone AS col
FROM benefits
WHERE phone!=0

UNION ALL

SELECT id, gym AS col
FROM benefits
WHERE gym!=0

UNION ALL

SELECT id, pension AS col
FROM benefits
WHERE pension !=0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to achieve this goal is by using `UNION ALL` , once for each column :

```
SELECT id,'Car' as val , car
FROM benefits WHERE car <> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT id,'Phone' as val , phone
FROM benefits WHERE phone <> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT id,'Car' as val , car
FROM benefits WHERE car <> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT id,'Gym' as val , Gym
FROM benefits WHERE Gym<> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT id,'Pension' as val , Pension 
FROM benefits WHERE Pension <> 0

order by id
```